# Combining objects with object destructuring and the turnary operator

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6, object-destructuring

I'm trying to detemine the style based on a few boolean variables (sticky and isHidden).

I know that I can combine 2 objects by using `{...object1, ...object2}`

I am trying to apply the same logic to a nested object, so that style would be the result of combining the objects `styles.stickyNav`, `styles.hide` and `styles.navBar` if both the booleans are true, and but just `style.navBar` if neither are true

```
const styles = {
  hide: {  
    top: -60
  },
  stickyNav: {
      height: 60,
      position: fixed
  },
  navBar:{
    display: 'flex',
    width: '100%',
    background: 'white',
    boxShadow: "0 10px 6px -6px #777"
  }
}

const style={
  sticky ? {...styles.stickyNav} : {},
  isHidden && sticky ? {...styles.hide} : {},
  {...style.navBar}
}
```

---

**Example output**

If both booleans are true, style should be

```js
{
  top: -60
  height: 60,
  position: fixed
  display: 'flex',
  width: '100%',
  background: 'white',
  boxShadow: "0 10px 6px -6px #777"
}
```

If neither are true, then style should be

```js
{
  display: 'flex',
  width: '100%',
  background: 'white',
  boxShadow: "0 10px 6px -6px #777"
}
```

if only sticky is true, then style should be

```js
{
  height: 60,
  position: fixed
  display: 'flex',
  width: '100%',
  background: 'white',
  boxShadow: "0 10px 6px -6px #777"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with the following, just using the spread operator in an initially empty object

```js
const styles = {
  hide: {  
    top: -60
  },
  stickyNav: {
      height: 60,
      position: 'fixed'
  },
  navBar:{
    display: 'flex',
    width: '100%',
    background: 'white',
    boxShadow: "0 10px 6px -6px #777"
  }
}

var sticky = true;
var isHidden = true;

/***Original ***/
/*const style={
  ...(sticky ? styles.stickyNav : {}),
  ...(isHidden && sticky ? styles.hide : {}),
  ...styles.navBar
}*/

/*Improved Based on comment*/
const style={
  ...(sticky && styles.stickyNav),
  ...((isHidden && sticky) && styles.hide),
  ...styles.navBar
}



console.log(style);
```

Note there were a couple of console errors that needed fixing

Comment: You could also do `...(sticky && styles.stickyNav)` and `...(isHidden && sticky && styles.hide)` because spreading a boolean returns an empty object

Comment: @adiga ooo nice, I've updated the answer based on this. I've used and additional () as it's a little more readable for me, it makes it more obvious what the comparison is.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like:

```
const style =
  isHidden && sticky
    ? { ...styles.hide, ...styles.stickyNav, ...styles.navBar }
    : sticky
    ? { ...styles.stickyNav, ...styles.navBar }
    : style.navBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
const style = sticky && isHidden ?
    { ...styles.hide, ...styles.stickyNav, ...styles.navBar   } :
    sticky ? { ...styles.stickyNav, ...styles.navBar } : { ...styles.navBar };
```

```js
let sticky =  true;
let isHidden = true;

const styles = {
  hide: {  
    top: -60
  },
  stickyNav: {
      height: 60,
      position: 'fixed'
  },
  navBar:{
    display: 'flex',
    width: '100%',
    background: 'white',
    boxShadow: "0 10px 6px -6px #777"
  }
}

const style = sticky && isHidden ?
    { ...styles.hide, ...styles.stickyNav, ...styles.navBar   } :
    sticky ? { ...styles.stickyNav, ...styles.navBar } : { ...styles.navBar };

console.log(style);
```